# Set value in JSON by a path using lodash or underscore

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I wanna set the value in a JSON using a path string like this `"a.0.b"` for a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  a: [
    {
      b: 'c'
    }
  ]
}
```

I came up with this solution but I wonder if there is a simpler way to write this:

```
function setValue(path, value, json) {
  var keys = path.split('.');
  _.reduce(keys, function(obj, key, i) {
    if (i === keys.length - 1) {
      obj[key] = value;
    } else {
      return obj[key];
    }
  }, json);
}
```

so calling `setValue('a.0.b', 'd', {a:[{b:'c'}]})` would change the json to `{a:[{b:'d'}]}`

Comment: FYI, JSON is a textual data-exchange format. What you are referring to in your question is a (nested) JavaScript object/array.

Comment: So would you like to set variables like `a[0].b = 1;`, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: In the `setvalue` would be passed a the path string, the new value and the json where the value should changed. Updated the question with an example.

Comment: In your example the `a` array does not contain a key of `'0'` (a string). You would have to convert the string into an integer to access the first index of the `a` array.

Comment: To be clear the posted function works well, I just wonder if the function could be simplified.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution.  I benchmarked the two possible solutions and it seems looping over object and path is faster than using the reduce function.  See the JSPerf tests here:  http://jsperf.com/set-value-in-json-by-a-path-using-lodash-or-underscore

```
function setValue(path, val, obj) {
  var fields = path.split('.');
  var result = obj;
  for (var i = 0, n = fields.length; i < n && result !== undefined; i++) {
    var field = fields[i];
    if (i === n - 1) {
      result[field] = val;
    } else {
      if (typeof result[field] === 'undefined' || !_.isObject(result[field])) {
        result[field] = {};
      }
      result = result[field];
    }
  }
}
```